# Set android bitmap size keeping aspect ratio based on minimum height and width

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm currently loading an image that can be either landscape or portrait.

I'm then wanting to resize the bitmap to draw directly onto a canvas for a full screen image.

I need keep the aspect ratio but have the image not fit to the screen but crop off any image that's bigger than the screen.

I can resize it and fit it to the screen with the following:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, MyWallpaperService.this.width, MyWallpaperService.this.height),     Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
```

but I don't want to have the black bars at the top/bottom or sides, but I can't think of the routine to resize correctly for this.

Comment: You can do that simply by setting ImageView ScaleType. Any reason of not using ScaleType.

Comment: It's for a live wallpaper where I'm drawing directly to the canvas and need to resize images to hold for quicker processing as the original image can be picked by the user they can be very large or smaller than the screen dimensions.

Comment: you don't need `Bitmap.createBitmap`, just use original `Bitmap` and the computed `Matrix` when calling `Canvas.drawBitmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are drawing the image onto the canvas yourself the first step is to calculate the dimensions required for the final image based on the screen size and the original image aspect ratio.

Then use the static function `createScaledBitmap` from the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class to resize your bitmap to match the calculated dimensions. Make sure you only call this function once and store the bitmap for use in the drawing routine.

Finally draw the bitmap so only the area of the bitmap you want to see is on the screen.

A more memory friendly approach is to add another step to crop the image using `Bitmap.createBitmap` before calling `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`. This reduces the chance of encountering memory issues caused by the user selecting a source image that is thin and long.